# Use string in intent .setData()

Tags: android

Hi I have a streaming app that streaming url is defined in itself.

I want the app to pick streaming url from webpage into String (I already done this).

But problem is that I am not able to put that string inside of .setData(Uri.parse());

in my code on line 27 I have String. I want to put that String content into `.setData` on line 90.

Here is my code : https://ideone.com/mw8ARE

```
private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    if(isConnected)
    {

       Intent mpdIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
        mpdIntent.setData(Uri.parse(channel))
                .putExtra(PlayerActivity.CONTENT_ID_EXTRA, "sbcms")
                .putExtra(PlayerActivity.CONTENT_TYPE_EXTRA, Util.TYPE_HLS)
                .putExtra(PlayerActivity.PROVIDER_EXTRA, "");
      startActivityForResult(mpdIntent,PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);

        //Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayerActivity.class);
       // startActivity(in);
    }
    else{
PlayOfflineContent();
    }
```

Update :

I am getting url from website in 
    String channel =''

My problem is that I am not able to put that String channel = url in mpdIntent

```
mpdIntent.setData(Uri.parse(channel))
```

this is not working

Comment: Instead of adding it along with Intent instance,try to use the variable mpdIntent.setData().

Comment: a streaming url like http://live.website.com/live/playlist.m3u8

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by-:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
i.putExtra("url","yourURL");
startActivity(i);
```

change your url here in code-:

```
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("YourUrl")
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions... still not getting String channel to intent. Code update according to suggestions

Comment: wats the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I am getting url from website in String channel, but not able to put that in mpdIntent.setData(Uri.parse(channel))... when I test the app it plays offline content. but if i put url directly on .setData it plays well

Comment: wats the url that you are using?

Comment: As I said already.... I am getting url from website, I changed real url bcoz of security.... my problem is that url is not going in intent....

Comment: then use intent.putExtra("url",value of url);

and in another activity use-:

intent.getStringExtra("url");

and set it wherever you want

Comment: ok, where I need to put  intent.putExtra("url",value of url);

Answer (score 0):

As per your code link , do check you execute DownloadWebPageTask in onCreate() method like below

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvdata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdata);
        new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();//change here
        checkConnection();

    }
```

Comment: hi,. thanks for point it... but i already hv this line... accidentally deleted when posting code... btw thanks

Comment: No... still not getting String channel to intent. Code updated according to suggestions